# error al usar archivos externos

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

introducir la descripción del enlace aquítengo un problema a la hora de calcular un archivo externo con la libreria I/O ya que mi programa trata de contar los espacios en blanco y darme un numero pero en vez de eso los ignora

```
from io import open

"""
archivo.txt

hola mundo
"""


archivo = open("texto.txt","r")

texto = archivo.readlines()


for i in texto:
    if texto == " ":
         print(texto.count())

else:
    print("no hay espacios en blanco")
```

Comment: Por favor, adjunta una copia de tu archivo que estás intentando leer para poder verificar si el problema no es del archivo en sí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Te salta alguna excepción? La función count recibe un argumento con el símbolo a buscar.

Fichero test:
https://pastebin.com/U7pBkEhT

Código:

```py
with open('test', 'r') as f: 
    txt = f.read()             
print(txt.count(" "))
```

> 14

Answer (score 0):

No estás usando el `for` y el `if` correctamente. El resultado de `readlines()` es una lista con cada línea, así que para contar el caracter puedes: usar otro `for` para encontrar cada espacio, o usando `str.count()` para que lo haga por ti; o también la solución propuesta en otra respuesta, de leer todo el texto y aplicarle `txt.count()`

```
k = open("texto.txt","r")
texto = k.readlines()
k.close()

espacios = 0
for linea in texto:
    espacios += linea.count(' ')

print("Espacios en blanco:", espacios)
```